# Can't get rid of unwanted stuff while scraping email addresses

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, web-scraping

I'm trying to capture email addresses from some site's landing pages using requests in combination with re module. This is the pattern `[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+` that I've used within the script to capture them.

When I run the script, I do get email addresses. However, I also get some unwanted stuff that resemble email addresses but in reality they are not and for that reason I would like to get rid of them.

```
import re
import requests

links = (
    'http://www.acupuncturetx.com',
    'http://www.hcmed.org',
    'http://www.drmindyboxer.com',
    'http://wendyrobinweir.com',
)

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"}

for link in links:
    r = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    emails = re.findall(r"[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+",r.text)
    print(emails)
```

Current output:

```
['react@16.5.2', 'react-dom@16.5.2', 'bai@acupuncturetx.com', 'bai@acupuncturetx.com', 'bai@acupuncturetx.com', 'bai@acupuncturetx.com']
['hh-logo@2x.png', 'hh-logo@2x.png', 'hh-logo@2x.png', 'hh-logo@2x-300x47.png']
['leaflet@1.7.1']
['8b4e078a51d04e0e9efdf470027f0ec1@sentry.wixpress.com', 'requirejs-bolt@2.3.6', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wixstores-client-cart-icon@1.797.0', 'wixstores-client-gallery@1.1634.0']
```

Expected output:

```
['bai@acupuncturetx.com', 'bai@acupuncturetx.com', 'bai@acupuncturetx.com', 'bai@acupuncturetx.com']
[]
[]
['wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com']
```

How can I only capture email addresses and get rid of unwanted stuff using regex?

Comment: Here are all of the valid TLDs according to ICANN https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt. You just need to add them all at the end like `[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.(?:aaa|aarp|abarth|abb|abbott)(?:[^\w\.-]|$)`

Comment: fyi, `email@ip_address` is also a valid email but if you don't expect to run into those then you can ignore this comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parting from where you left, you can use a simply checker to verify if it's really a valid email.

So first we define the check function:

```py
def check(email):
    regex = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w+$'
    if re.match(regex, email):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then we use it to check your itens on your email list:

```py
for link in links:
    r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    emails_list = re.findall(r"[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+", r.text)
    emails_list = [email for email in emails_list if check(email)]
    print(emails_list)
```

#### Outputs:

```
['bai@acupuncturetx.com', 'bai@acupuncturetx.com', 'bai@acupuncturetx.com', 'bai@acupuncturetx.com']
[]
[]
['wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

I happen to have a regex such as this that respects [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321), which will help you weed out a lot of bogus (ie: non-local) email addresses, but not all. The code can easily be adapted to ignore more stuff should you want to...

For example, email `8b4e078a51d04e0e9efdf470027f0ec1@...` does look bogus, but the "local name" part is technically correct as per the RFC... You could add checks on the local-name part (will be `match.group(1)` in my code snippet below)

Here's my code tidbit with the RFC-compliant regex in question:

```
# See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321
EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile(r"([\w.~%+-]{1,64})@([\w-]{1,64}\.){1,16}(\w{2,16})", re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE)


# Cache this (it doesn't change often), all official top-level domains
TLD_URL = "https://datahub.io/core/top-level-domain-names/r/top-level-domain-names.csv.json"
OFFICIAL_TLD = requests.get(TLD_URL).json()
OFFICIAL_TLD = [x["Domain"].lstrip(".") for x in OFFICIAL_TLD]


def extracted_emails(text):
    for match in EMAIL_REGEX.finditer(text):
        top_level = match.group(3)
        if top_level in OFFICIAL_TLD:
            email = match.group(0)
            # Additionally, max length of domain should be at most 255
            # You could also simplify this to simply: len(email) < 255
            if len(top_level) + len(match.group(2)) < 255:
                yield email


# ... 8< ... stripped unchanged code for brevity

for link in links:
    r = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    emails = list(extracted_emails(r.text))
    print(emails)
```

This yields your expected results + the one bogus (but technically correct) `8b4e078a51d04e0e9efdf470027f0ec1@...` email.

It uses a regex that strictly complies to RFC 5321, and double-checks the top-level domain against the official list for each substring that looks like a valid email.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest fix for this is to realize that the top level domain is always alphabetic and that the subdomain components are always like *"foo."*.

**EDIT** More comprehensive look arounds.

```perl
/(?!<[\w.-])[\w.-]+@(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,}(?![A-Za-z0-9.-])/
```

You can always exclude certain string components with a negative look ahead. `\.(?!gif|png|jpg)\w+`

To exclude long hex sequences do this.

```perl
/(?!(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2})+@)/

# all together now
/(?!<[\w.-])(?!(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2})+@)[\w.-]+@(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,}(?![A-Za-z0-9.-])/
```

Incidentally, here is Perl's regex for an email address.

```perl
qr/(?^:(?:(?^:(?>(?^:(?^:(?>(?^:(?>(?^:(?>(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*[^\x00-\x1F\x7F()<>\[\]:;@\\,."\s]+(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*))|\.|\s*"(?^:(?^:[^\\"])|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D])))+"\s*))+))|(?>(?^:(?^:(?>(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*[^\x00-\x1F\x7F()<>\[\]:;@\\,."\s]+(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*))|(?^:(?>(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*"(?^:(?^:[^\\"])|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D])))*"(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*)))+))?)(?^:(?>(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*<(?^:(?^:(?^:(?>(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*(?^:(?>[^\x00-\x1F\x7F()<>\[\]:;@\\,."\s]+(?:\.[^\x00-\x1F\x7F()<>\[\]:;@\\,."\s]+)*))(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*))|(?^:(?>(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*"(?^:(?^:[^\\"])|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D])))*"(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*)))\@(?^:(?^:(?>(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*(?^:(?>[^\x00-\x1F\x7F()<>\[\]:;@\\,."\s]+(?:\.[^\x00-\x1F\x7F()<>\[\]:;@\\,."\s]+)*))(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*))|(?^:(?>(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*\[(?:\s*(?^:(?^:[^\[\]\\])|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))))*\s*\](?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*))))>(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*)))|(?^:(?^:(?^:(?>(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*(?^:(?>[^\x00-\x1F\x7F()<>\[\]:;@\\,."\s]+(?:\.[^\x00-\x1F\x7F()<>\[\]:;@\\,."\s]+)*))(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*))|(?^:(?>(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*"(?^:(?^:[^\\"])|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D])))*"(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*)))\@(?^:(?^:(?>(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*(?^:(?>[^\x00-\x1F\x7F()<>\[\]:;@\\,."\s]+(?:\.[^\x00-\x1F\x7F()<>\[\]:;@\\,."\s]+)*))(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*))|(?^:(?>(?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*\[(?:\s*(?^:(?^:[^\[\]\\])|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))))*\s*\](?^:(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))|(?>\s+))*)))))(?>(?^:(?>\s*\((?:\s*(?^:(?^:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?^:\\(?^:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*))*))/
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Instead of only capturing e-mail addresses, you can test everything you capture with the package validate_email (`pip install validate_email`) and retain only valid ones. The code would be some version of the code below:

```py
from validate_email import validate_email
emails = [x if validate_email(x) else '' for x in list_of_potential_emails]
```

This package checks with the corresponding server if the e-mail (or the server) exists.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code as below:

```
import re
import requests

links = (
    'http://www.acupuncturetx.com',
    'http://www.hcmed.org',
    'http://www.drmindyboxer.com',
    'http://wendyrobinweir.com',
)

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"}


def check(email):
    regex = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
    if (re.search(regex, email)):
        return email

Email_List = []

for link in links:
    r = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    emails = re.findall(r"[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+",r.text)
    for email in emails:
        valid_email = check(email)
        if valid_email!= None:
            Email_List.append(valid_email)

    print(Email_List)
    Email_List.clear()
```

Comment: That regex misses a lot of emails. Also TLDs are not just 2 or 3 letters - consider `.co.uk` or `.business`

Answer (score 0):

This regex should catch most of them:

```
print( re.findall(r"\b[\w.%+-]+@[\w.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,8}(?<!gif|jpg|png)\b", '''
['react@16.5.2', 'react-dom@16.5.2', 'bai@acupuncturetx.com', 'bai@acupuncturetx.com', 'bai@acupuncturetx.com', 'bai@acupuncturetx.com']
['hh-logo@2x.png', 'hh-logo@2x.png', 'hh-logo@2x.png', 'hh-logo@2x-300x47.png']
['leaflet@1.7.1']
['8b4e078a51d04e0e9efdf470027f0ec1@sentry.wixpress.com', 'requirejs-bolt@2.3.6', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wendyrobin16@gmail.com', 'wixstores-client-cart-icon@1.797.0', 'wixstores-client-gallery@1.1634.0']
''', re.IGNORECASE) )
```

There's an extra negative lookbehind at the end for special cases

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's true for all the links in `links`, but at least for those in your question (and from what I can tell, in many cases), the common denominator seems to be that the spurious, email-like strings are all inside a `<script>` tag, while actual email addresses (if any) are found both inside and outside that tag. So the following will skip anything inside that tag (and, incidentally, remove a lot of duplication). If you are lucky and there are email addresses outside that, this should capture them:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
for link in links:
    r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    for em in soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r"[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+")):
      if em.parent.name != "script":
        print(em)
```

With your 4 links, the output would be

```
bai@acupuncturetx.com
```

for the first, nothing for the 2nd and 3rd and

```
wendyrobin16@gmail.com
wendyrobin16@gmail.com
```

For the last one. Try it on your actual `links` and see if it gets you close enough.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your case, you can just make that the domain names end by a valid TLDs and sub TLDs.  Here is a pretty comprehensive list of them:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains
2. Alternatively, if you are too lazy to do this, and if you don't mind extra delay in parsing email addresses, you may simply perform a DNS lookup for every found email address candidate to see if you can get an MX entry.  Then treat it as a domain name only when it does have an MX entry.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. How to discard matches we don't want
2. How to make it maintainable

## 1. How to discard matches we don't want

We can decide if we the match is good or not based on what's in the right hand side of the @ character without having to install/use more python modules.

The idea is to put a negative lookahead in your regex after the '@' character to match the stuff you don't want. If the content of the negative lookahead matches, you won't get that result.

Your regex will go from this:

```
[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+
         ^^^^^^^^---> We can decide based on what's here
```

To this:

```
[\w\.-]+@(?! **STUFF_I_DO_NOT_WANT_TO_MATCH_AFTER_THIS_POINT** )[\w\.-]+
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           \-> Look ahead for the regex inside (?! ) and 
               continue if it does not match.
```

In order to discard the string, we need to look for:

- strings with digits and dots: `[\d\.]+`
- known file extensions at the end of the string: `(png|other_extension)$`

If we mach any of the conditions above, we can discard the string.
We can consctruct the negative loookahead with an OR condition like this: `(?![\d\.]+|(png|other_extension)$])`.

Adding the neg. lookahead after the `@` we get this regex:

```
[\w\.-]+@(?![\d\.]+|(png|other_extension)$)[\w\.-]+
```

## 2. How to make it easy to maintain?

The problem with regexes is they become unmantainable quickly.

You can read them without trouble while you're working in the problem; but after some time you might need to change the regex without frying your brain.

To mitigate this a biut you can define the regex in python this way:

```
email_regex = (r'[\w\.-]+@'    # Left hand side of the email - characters and dots.
               r'?![\d\.]+|(png|other_file_extension)$'  # Stuff we don't want at the end of the @ (not valid domains like digits and file extensions
               r'[\w\.-]'      # Email domain
              )

# Look for emails
emails = re.findall(email_regex,r.text)
```

This works because in python you can concatenate stings just separating them with withespace (just try `"123asd" == "123" "asd"`)